# installing ROS-Electric - not enough free space

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

### Hi everybody
I am trying to install ROS-Electric on Ubuntu 11.10 (Onereic). I follow the instructions provided at the ROS download site but when I type the command
:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-electric-desktop-full
I get the following message at the end.

### 7 upgraded, 381 newly installed, 0 to remove and 391 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,071 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,824 MB of additional disk space will be used.
E: You don't have enough free space in /var/cache/apt/archives/.

I searched on ubuntu question/answers and at some point I found that I should use the command "sudo apt-get clean" to cleanup space in /var/cache/apt/archives. No luck, I still get the same message.

Can somebody help with this?
Thank you all.
George

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44090/installing-ros-electric---not-enough-free-space/) by [agrirobot-George](https://answers.ros.org/users/3227/agrirobot-george/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like the partition /var is mounted on. It is likely that you will not have enough space for extracting ros either Maybe you can increase it using something like gparted or create separate partitions for /var and /opt.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the command:

```
# df -h
```

and check the size of the partition you have allocated for /var

---

Originally posted by [Jakub](https://answers.ros.org/users/2948/jakub/) with karma: 1821 on 2012-09-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1